# Using Toshiba 22EL833 as PC display through HDMI input

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, dvi

I had another Toshiba TV - 19SL738 - connected to this same PC and video card (GTX 8800) through a DVI to HDMI cable (DVI on PC side, HDMI on TV) that was working perfectly at it's native resolution 1360x768.

Some time ago I had to change to the Toshiba 22EL833 and immediately faced a problem with Windows 7 Control Panel and NVIDIA control panel both reporting native resolution for new TV as 1080i (1920x1280), despite TV documentation saying that it have same 1360x768 as previous one.

Practical tests confirmed that true native resolution is indeed 1360x768, because plugging in through DVI to VGA and setting custom resolution through NVIDIA panel shown clear colors and crisp image. Meanwhile, any other setting with either DVI to VGA or DVI to  HDMI produced horribly distorted or squished images, with almost unreadable slim lines (as in letters, for example).

Now, my problem is that there's no drivers for this TV and I'm unable to get good image while connecting it through DVI<->HDMI directly. The best I've achieved is editing EDID/driver manually, to persuade system that native resolution should be 1360x768, and while image became mostly clear, colors turned to some strange washed out effect, with pools of pure yellow, cyan and magenta there and there filling place of other colors. Gradients also became noticeably stripped as well. Somehow it looks like dithering gone bad and makes me suspect that image is still down/upscaled several times internally somewhere along the line.

How can I connect this TV to DVI output of my video card to get best possible clear image, correct colors and correct native resolution?

Answer (score 0):

On the Q&A section of the owners manual, page 42 [Toshiba owners manual](http://www.toshiba-om.net/LCD/PDF/English/EL833-1922-English.pdf) sounds similar to your image quality.

> **Q** Why are there horizontal stripes and/or blurred images on the screen
> when in PC mode?
>
> **A** The Phase may need adjustment. Select PC Settings and highlight
> Phase and adjust until the picture cleared.

Also check out page 25 - Configuring PC picture setting (one portion below)

> **Phase**
>
> Depending on the resolution and scan frequency that you input to
> the TV Set, you may see a hazy or noisy picture on the screen. In such
> a case you can use this item to get a clear picture by trial and error
> method.
>
> • In the PC POSITION menu press the Down button until Phase is highlighted.
>
> • Press the Left or Right button to adjust the value.

There is little more on the Toshiba document side. Consider also contacting Toshiba support and they should be able to give precise direction. [Contact Toshiba support](http://eu.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/contact_toshiba.jsp/)

Comment: Phase/position settings is not applicable, because I'm using HDMI input and they only affect VGA. I did contact them (Russian support though, didn't try global one yet) and response was: "we can't guarantee it will work with every PC. Try using another PC *(gee, thanks!)* or go to service".